# Add-AzureVHD : VHD size is too large - but it's only 70GB

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I try to upload a 78GB VHD file to Azure. The VHD was created with Disk2vhd. It is not an OS disk, but the image of a datadrive (drive f:)

However, on Add-AzueVHD I get the following error:

```
Add-AzureVHD : VHD size is too large ('2.000.343.269.888'), maximum allowed size is '1.099.511.627.776'.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Add-AzureVHD –LocalfilePath $sourcevhd –Destination $destinationvhd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-AzureVhd], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.StorageServices.AddAzureVhdCommand
```

The commands I am using are as follows:

```
Add-AzureAccount
Select-AzureSubscription "mysubscname" -CurrentStorageAccountName mystorageaccountname
Set-AzureSubscription –SubscriptionName "mysubscname" –CurrentStorageAccountName "mystorageaccountname"
$sourcevhd=”z:\DATENB.vhd”
$destinationvhd = “https://mystorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/mystoragecontainer/DATENB.vhd”
Add-AzureVHD –LocalfilePath $sourcevhd –Destination $destinationvhd
```

I am using a free testing account. 
The storage account "mystorageaccountname" is of classic type and set up in the azure portal. It is listed correctly when issuing a Get-AzureSubscription.

Any idea what the issue could be? The VHD file is for sure just 78GB. the original disk size was 780GB with only 124GB of data. The resulting VHD is now 78GB.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Vhds have to be fixed in size not dynamic. If the file you're uploading is only 78gb - it's not fixed.

Comment: Thanks. So, Add-AzureVHD reads the content of the VHD and determines it's size? If so, why does it then report **2.000.343.269.888** (2TB?) as the size and not either 780GB (which was the original disk size) or 124GB (unlikely, yet this is the used up space)?

Comment: Has to be a red herring. Once you have a fixed size vhd, it should upload fine as the max size in Azure is 1tb

Comment: I see. can I give the vhd a fixed size? if yes, how?

Comment: There's a powershell cmdlet. https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh848454.aspx

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks.